# Sunrise-Sunset API returning unexpected responses

Tags: python

I am trying to send API calls to [api.sunrise-sunset.org](https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json) to get the sunset/sunrise time. This works fine however the problem is whenever I send an API call with `lat` and `lng` parameters it returns an unexpected response.

**For example.**

The below code returns a correct value of sunrise and sunset(Without lat/lng parameters)

```py
import requests

response = requests.get(url = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json")
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

**API Response:**

```
{'results': {'sunrise': '5:47:00 AM', 'sunset': '5:55:48 PM', 'solar_noon': '11:51:24 AM', 'day_length': '12:08:48', 'civil_twilight_begin': '5:27:24 AM', 'civil_twilight_end': '6:15:24 PM', 'nautical_twilight_begin': '5:03:23 AM', 'nautical_twilight_end': '6:39:25 PM', 'astronomical_twilight_begin': '4:39:23 AM', 'astronomical_twilight_end': '7:03:25 PM'}, 'status': 'OK'}
```

However when I try to send the API call with the `lat` and `lng` parameters it returns a very wierd response. My location is Pakistan.

For example the below code returns 12:56:37 AM as a sunrise time which is really wierd to me.

```py
import requests
LAT = 33.648953
LNG = 73.177007

parameters = {
    "lat":LAT,
    "lng":LNG

}


response = requests.get(url = "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json", params=parameters)
response.raise_for_status()
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

**API Response:**

```
{'results': {'sunrise': '12:56:37 AM', 'sunset': '1:00:55 PM', 'solar_noon': '6:58:46 AM', 'day_length': '12:04:18', 'civil_twilight_begin': '12:33:03 AM', 'civil_twilight_end': '1:24:28 PM', 'nautical_twilight_begin': '12:04:07 AM', 'nautical_twilight_end': '1:53:24 PM', 'astronomical_twilight_begin': '11:34:57 PM', 'astronomical_twilight_end': '2:22:35 PM'}, 'status': 'OK'}
```

What could go wrong? I tried changing the values of LAT/LNG but still same issue.

**I tried:**

1. Cross checking the longitude and latitude values from the [latlong.net](https://www.latlong.net/) and they are perfectly valid.
2. I tried getting a response from the browser directly and it also shows a wierd sunset/sunrise time. [api call with lat and lng](https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json?lat=33.6938118&lng=73.0651511)

[image: API response from the browser]

Comment: Times are UTC - Did you look at their documentation?

Comment: Edit: Checking their docs. The times are indeed in UTC.

Comment: What is there to fix? There's nothing wrong. The API doesn't know where you are so it has to use normalised dates/times

Comment: Alright, I used UTC+5 for Pakistan and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the api documentation at [sunrise-sunset.org](https://sunrise-sunset.org/api):

> NOTE: All times are in UTC and summer time adjustments are not included in the returned data.

So you have to transform it to UTC +5 for Pakistan.

Comment: Can you edit your answer so it is easily readable? The first line is a hard to read. Thank you

Comment: hope it is more clear now